# How secure data being received from ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php

I am not an engineer. I am simply testing myself by trying to build a LITTLE website for a local chat purpose. I have built all the website but I face a problem. For example, if someone send a text to another one, the data are sent to a server, but are not encrypted. I have tried to imagine how i can secure data sent to server but i cannot. I simply encrypt them to the database (using php). The same for data sent from server to client. even if i can encrypt data in the server before sending to the client, i will not be able to decrypt them in the client. any help (giving a solution or saying it possible or not) is welcome.

Comment: Use https, and then the data transfer will be encrypted for you

Comment: The application doesn't encrypt the communication, then channel does.  In this case the channel is HTTP, so you'd use HTTPS (SSL) to encrypt the communications between the client and the server.  This channel encryption is entirely transparent to the application itself.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.